# IIS7 SMTP: SmartHost or local SMTP Server?

Tags: smtp, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET 4 application that has been in production for years running on Windows Server 2008 R2. It sends email, and is currently configured to send to a specific SmartHost.

I would like to eliminate the dependency on that SmartHost server (it might be going away). As I see it, I have two options:

1. Find another SmartHost - possibly in the cloud? Which concerns me because it's another point of failure and dependency.
2. Install & configure SMTP server on the same box as the application. I'm not wild about installing the 'IIS6-bits' that seem necessary to do this.

What's the best practice here? Are folks using external servers via SmartHost more or are you installing local SMTP servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have chosen option 2, because, as you wrote, this eliminates another point of failure, namely the network path between your server and the smart host. Administering a send only mail server is not a big deal. I set up a local send only mail server about two years ago, and except an upgrade I did not do anything with it. Even the upgrade was not strictly necessary. I have to add that I was not completely new to configuring a mail server, and we already had a second mail server, giving additional safety.
On the other hand I have no experience with the SMTP server included in IIS (I only tried it once, several years ago, without success, and gave it up immediately), and I also found then that the choice of open source mail servers on Windows is limited.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with IIS6 SMTP Server although I've only used it to relay to another SmartHost (GMail) and not had it send mail itself. It's a little tricky to set up but [not that hard](http://www.smtp2go.com/docs/iis/) and has worked well for me.

Note: The IIS bits are still there even in Server 2012 and although deprecated Microsoft has provided no replacement. See my thoughts on [What replaces IIS SMTP server in Windows Server 2012](https://serverfault.com/questions/455724/what-replaces-iis-smtp-server-in-windows-server-2012/476701#476701)  on ServerFault.

I'd recommend using both IIS6 bits in conjunction with an external SmartHost (I use Gmail) for the benefits in the above referenced ServerFault answer of mine. I would think that [setting up your own SMTP server](http://www.emailmarketingsoftwareguide.com/outgoing-mail-smtp-server.html) is going to end up being more complicated and you may risk being blacklisted if you're not careful.